# picker will only display 3 objects

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, crash, picker

I have a three component picker with the third being dependant on the first two. This dependancy works perfect when there are only 3 items in each component. When there is more than three in the final component (which changes based on the values of the other two it crashes when trying to move the reel.

The error received is " *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[_PFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (3) beyond bounds (3)' "

I can't work out where it is getting this bounds of 3 from. This is not the full implementation I have functions in view did loads to populate the arrays used and a button with logic to use the values on a button press. Please let me know if you think these could be the problem. I appreciate any comments or help. Thanks

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 3;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", moduleCount];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Module selected" message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];

    if (component == kPartComponent) {
        return [self.parts count];
    }
    else if (component == kSubjectComponent) {
        return [self.courses count];
    }
    else return moduleCount; // problem is likely to be here where i return the count, the picker is only showing 3 modules for each section not the full amount





}

#pragma mark Picker Delegate Methods
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {



    Parts *p = [self.parts objectAtIndex:row];

    Course *c = [self.courses objectAtIndex:row];

    Modules *m = [self.modules objectAtIndex:row];


    if (component == kPartComponent) {
        return p.part;
    }

    else if (component == kModuleComponent) {
        return m.name;
    }

    else return c.course;


}

- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if(component == 0)
        return 40.0;
    else if(component == 1)
        return 85.0;
    else
        return 125.0;

}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {


     if (component == kSubjectComponent) { 

     Course *selectedCourse;
     selectedCourse = [self.courses objectAtIndex:row];
     NSString *courseComp = [selectedCourse valueForKey:@"course"];

     AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

     NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegate managedObjectContext];

     NSEntityDescription *entityModules = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Modules" inManagedObjectContext:context];

     NSFetchRequest *fetchRequestModules = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
     [fetchRequestModules setEntity:entityModules];

     NSPredicate * modSubCondition = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(courses.course == %@)", courseComp];
     NSPredicate * modPartCondition = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(parts.part == %@)", globalPart];
     NSPredicate * compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:modSubCondition, modPartCondition, nil]];

     [fetchRequestModules setPredicate:compoundPredicate]; 

     NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorModules = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES]; // This definitely works, proven by changing the ascending bool.
     NSArray *sortDescriptorsModules = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptorModules, nil]; 

     [fetchRequestModules setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptorsModules];

     NSArray *modulesArray = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequestModules error:nil];


         globalSubject = courseComp;

     self.modules = modulesArray;

         moduleCount = [self.modules count];



     [picker selectRow:0 inComponent:kModuleComponent animated:YES];
     [picker reloadComponent:kModuleComponent];
     } 

     else if (component == kPartComponent) { 

     Parts *selectedParts;
     selectedParts = [self.parts objectAtIndex:row];
     NSString *partsComponent = [selectedParts valueForKey:@"part"];

     AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

     NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegate managedObjectContext];

     NSEntityDescription *entityModules = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Modules" inManagedObjectContext:context];

     NSFetchRequest *fetchRequestModules = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
     [fetchRequestModules setEntity:entityModules];

     NSPredicate * modSubCondition = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(courses.course == %@)", globalSubject];
     NSPredicate * modPartCondition = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(parts.part == %@)", partsComponent];
     NSPredicate * compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:modSubCondition, modPartCondition, nil]];

     [fetchRequestModules setPredicate:compoundPredicate]; 

     NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorModules = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES]; // This definitely works, proven by changing the ascending bool.
     NSArray *sortDescriptorsModules = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptorModules, nil]; 

     [fetchRequestModules setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptorsModules];

     NSArray *modulesArray = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequestModules error:nil];


         globalPart = partsComponent;

     self.modules = modulesArray;

         moduleCount = [self.modules count];



     [picker selectRow:0 inComponent:kModuleComponent animated:YES];
     [picker reloadComponent:kModuleComponent];

     } 

}
```

Comment: why do u want the alertview in numberOfRowsInComponent?

Comment: I used that to try and work out the number of items in the array which it should draw to check that the array is bigger than three objects.

Comment: can u comment code in numberOfRowsInComponent and just give return 3 or 5.

Comment: I have done that and when I return 3, all works fine but only shows 3 rows as expected. When I return 5 it crashes when I try to scroll ay component with the same error. as previous "index (3) beyond bounds (3).

Answer (score 0):

As each component seems to be dependent on the others for its contents, it looks like you should be reloading the entire picker when you change the module or the subject, or you risk having the wrong size of array for the count you are giving, which would indeed give you the error you're getting.

Edit - had a closer look at your code!

Your implementation of -

```
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

...is wrong!

You are using the same row variable to access all 3 arrays at once, without checking which one is needed, so if row is say, 16, for the component, it will also be trying to get objectAtIndex:16 for your modules array too. You need to check which array you're accessing, in the same way you do in the other methods.

Comment: I just tried [picker reloadAllComponents] and [picker reloadInputViews] but I have the same issue. Not all components are dependant on each other. The third component is dependant on the values of components 1 and 2 but not but 1 and 2 are not dependant on anything they are fixed. And each of them has 3 objects which may be where this bound 3 is coming from but I can't see where I have gone wrong.